# App is stuck on loading screen on android emulator

Tags: android, react-native

I am new to react-native and I want to build and run a simple application. It was working fine but when I close the emulator and try to run it again, the android emulator is stuck on the loading screen. 
The build is successful. I run `react-native start` on one terminal and then `react-native run-android` in another terminal. This was the output of the terminal when I run-android.

```
BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 2s
26 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 25 up-to-date
info Running adb -s emulator-5554 reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081
info Starting the app on emulator-5554 (adb -s emulator-5554 shell am start -n com.myapp/com.myapp.MainActivity)...
Starting: Intent { cmp=com.myapp/.MainActivity }

My emulator is Nexus 5X, API version 28, memory 1536 MB.
react-native-cli version: 2.0.1
react-native version: 0.59.3
```

I'm using ubuntu 18.04 and the RAM capacity is 8gb.

I am sure there is no error in the code, because it worked fine previously.

I tried deleting the node modules and cleaning the cache and then npm install. But still couldn't get it running

Comment: `android emulator is stuck on the loading screen` isn't this a problem with the emulator and not with react-native?

Comment: I don't know exactly with what the problem is. Are you suggesting to add emulator as a tag?

Comment: Try closing everything and only start the emulator run react-native only after the emulator is ready

Comment: Did u try checking the real time logs? like adb logcat ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it works for me when i restart watchman server, clear the cache, delete the node modules and do a npm install.

```
echo 256 | sudo tee -a /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_instances 
echo 32768 | sudo tee -a /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_queued_events 
echo 65536 | sudo tee -a /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_watches 
watchman shutdown-server 
npm cache clear 
rm -rf node_modules/ 
npm install
```

Answer (score 0):

one thing to try. In the terminal type

adb kill-server

adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081

adb start-server

[Adb information](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb)

Tbh it's usually code error since latest updates have made emulator much more stable, but reading about adb is a worth it, it's a  good resource.

Comment: Sorry to here that, I use ubuntu 18.04 as well, I have permission errors often with android emulator,  but you would have had warnings for that. Sorry I couldn't help. Maybe worth posting your code?

Comment: @Muaz I was looking at my setup, I realised. In our ubuntu version, I can't use remote debug at present. It just hangs even though its loaded. Ctrl + m. To disable it, maybe this check this if you haven't solved it yet?

Answer (score 0):

run this command it will increase max_user_watches

```
echo 999999 | sudo tee -a /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_watches
```

then try again. If issue still persist

```
watchman watch-del-all
watchman shutdown-server
```

should work